# TASM checking arguments when cx is modified

Tags: assembly, x86, command-line-arguments, dos, tasm

I need to check whether good amount of arguments is given. Currently my program knows when there are no arguments and when there are more than two arguments given. If one is given, then it is bad, but my program doesn't recognise it. I can't do simple check because there is one possibility when it is allowed (when /? is argument) and cx changes with loop. For example, if I call it prog /?, it should print description, when I call it prog arg1 arg2, it should be allowed, but prog arg1 shouldn't. How can I check that?

```
  mov ch, 0h         
  mov cl, [es:0080h] 
  push cx
  cmp cx, 0         
  je print_description

  mov bx, 81h          
  jmp search_help

  jmp exit

search_help:
  cmp [es:bx], '?/'  
  je print_description 
  inc bx               
  loop search_help    


  pop cx
  cmp cx, 2
  jne print_description
  mov bx, 82h     
  mov si, offset input_filename 
  mov cx, 255                   

search_input_filename:
  mov dl, [es:bx]               
  inc bx                       
  cmp dl, 20h                  
  je search_output_filename_prep

  mov ds:[si], dl               
  inc si                       
  loop search_input_filename 

search_output_filename_prep:
  mov si, offset output_filename 

search_output_filename:
  mov dl, [es:bx]            
  inc bx                     
  cmp dl, 0Dh             
  je program               
  cmp dl, 20h             
  je print_description     

  mov ds:[si], dl         
  inc si                     
  loop search_output_filename
```

Comment: That's easy, just check whether you have 2 arguments after you have failed to find a `/?`.

Comment: but mycx is changed, i don't know how to get it to compare, pushing cx and then popping doesn't work :(

Comment: pushing and popping should work, just as well as reloading from memory (or even just using the `cmp` with memory operand).

Comment: but it doesn't. what about the second thing? could you give me some sample since I don't have a clue what you are talking about (im learning TASM not in english)

Comment: Note that the byte at `80h` does not give you the number of arguments, it gives you the length of the command line. That's probably why your code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1) My TASM 5.0 doesn't like `[ES:xxxx]`. The segment override has to be written as `ES:[xxxx]`.

2) `ES:[0080h]` contains the length of the command line, **not** the count of the arguments. Thus this lines **don't** do what you think:

```
push cx
...
pop cx
cmp cx, 2
jne print_description
```

You can use my `get_argc` function instead. Following test case works (hopefully):

```
LOCALS @@
.MODEL small
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
    description db 'description',13,10,'$'
    input_filename db 80 DUP ('$')
    output_filename db 80 DUP ('$')

.CODE
main PROC
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        mov ch, 0h
        mov cl, es:[0080h]
        cmp cx, 0
        je print_description

        mov bx, 81h
        jmp search_help

        jmp exit

    search_help:
        cmp word ptr es:[bx], '?/'
        je print_description
        inc bx
        loop search_help

        call get_argc
        cmp ax, 2
        jne print_description

        mov bx, 82h
        mov si, offset input_filename
        mov cx, 255

    search_input_filename:
        mov dl, es:[bx]
        inc bx
        cmp dl, 20h
        je search_output_filename_prep

        mov ds:[si], dl
        inc si
        loop search_input_filename

    search_output_filename_prep:
        mov si, offset output_filename

    search_output_filename:
        mov dl, es:[bx]
        inc bx
        cmp dl, 0Dh
        je program
        cmp dl, 20h
        je print_description

        mov ds:[si], dl
        inc si
        loop search_output_filename

    program:
        mov dx, OFFSET input_filename
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        call crlf
        mov dx, OFFSET output_filename
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

    exit:
        mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h

    print_description:
        lea dx, description
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        mov ax, 4C01h
        int 21h

main ENDP

get_argc PROC
    mov bx, 0
    mov di, 80h
    mov cx, es:[di]

    @@L1:
        inc di
        mov al, es:[di]
        cmp al, 20h
        je @@L1
        cmp al, 09h
        je @@L1
        cmp al, 0Dh
        je @@done

        inc bx

    @@L2:
        inc di
        mov al, es:[di]
        cmp al, 20h
        je @@L1
        cmp al, 09h
        je @@L1
        cmp al, 0Dh
        je @@done
        jmp @@L2

    @@done:
        mov ax, bx
        ret
get_argc ENDP


crlf PROC
        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, 13
        int 21h
        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, 10
        int 21h
        ret
crlf ENDP

END main
```

Comment: my TASM 3.1, which is requirement in my uni, doesn't understand get_argc.

Comment: @Tomas: TASM 2.01, 3.0, 3.2, 4.0: no problems. Nevertheless I slightly changed the code (deleted `.386`-directive).

Comment: what LOCALS @@ actually does? I copied call get_argc; cmp ax, 22; jne print_description. compiler says "undefined symbol: get_argc"

Comment: @Tomas: I posted a whole program. You can take it, compile it and run it. If you call a procedure you should have a procedure. Look in your text editor for the symbol "get_argc" (all occurences). Hint: The procedure begins with `PROC` and ends with `ENDP`. LOCALS @@ makes all labels that are prefixed with @@ local, i.e. only known from a non-local label (without prefix) until the next non-local label.