# How to read command line arguments in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm, command-line-arguments

I'm using the TASM assembler and I can't seem to find a way to save my command line arguments or even output them. I tried doing `int 21h` while `dx=0081h` and `ah=09h`. It doesn't do anything although I've read that it is the way to do it.

I've added the code of what I think should work to copy and display an argument I type in:

```
mov dx, 81h
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
```

Comment: Please specify your target environment (OS or freestanding).

Comment: int 21h/ah=81h isn't a DOS interrupt that would help here. What did you think it would do?

Comment: Also provide your current approach in a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You haven't read it [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-3241.htm). Try my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27114927/3512216)..

Comment: @MichaelPetch i got it wrong my bad, ah=09h , dx= 81h

Answer (score 7):

The command line resides in the [Program Segment Prefix (PSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix), and there from position 81h. At position 80h you find the length of the string. This string always ends with a `0Dh`, not `$` (Pay attention for that if you want to use `int 21h/ah=09h`).

At the start of an .exe program the segment registers `DS` and `ES` point to that PSP. This is the reason why you have to load DS at the beginning of the program with the DATA segment (`mov ax, @data`;`mov ds, ax`). Let's skip that one:

```
MODEL small
.STACK 100h

.CODE

main PROC

    ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2791.htm
    mov ah, 40h         ; DOS 2+ - WRITE - WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    mov bx, 1           ; File handle = STDOUT
    xor ch, ch
    mov cl, ds:[0080h]  ; CX: number of bytes to write
    mov dx, 81h         ; DS:DX -> data to write (command line)
    int 21h             ; Call MSDOS

    ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm
    mov ax, 4C00h       ; AH=4Ch, AL=00h -> exit (0)
    int 21h             ; Call MSDOS
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: @rknb, when doing  `mov cl, ds:[0080h]` and `mov dx, 81h` we are adressing  adjacent places in memory, right? When I remove `ds` from the first line - program stops working correctly. But then why we can omit the segment name from the second line, and it still works?

Comment: @OlgaZhukova: Yes. This is a workaround for a TASM peculiarity. If you write only "`mov cl, [0080h]`", you get the warning "`[Constant] assumed to mean immediate constant`" and TASM assembles the line to "`mov cl, 80h`".  In the second line I send just a constant to MSDOS that will later use `DS:DX` as an address.